# How fire up modal window with different content by clicking different images

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, gallery

How i can fire up a modal window by clicking an image.
Also: different images b clicking open different content.
I will show a portfolio, and by click the image a modal fire up and show other images for this work. 
I don't ask code, but how/concept make this.

see picture what i mean:
(stupid tiping error "portfolio" :-))) )

[image: example for modal "gallery"]

Or a great example are [behance.net](https://www.behance.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine which element is clicked when you open the modal, 
by passing it as a parameter to a function that changes the content of the modal to get access to the clicked element content.

Comment: also in javascript